# Resolving imports by namespace with MEF

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, namespaces, ioc-container, mef

I'm using MEF as an IoC container.

If the requesting class is in the Foo.UI.* namespace, I want `ILogger` to resolve to `ClientLogger`, otherwise it should resolve to `Logger`. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with such a workaround, using named exports ?

```
[Export("clientLogger", typeof(ILogger))]
public class ClientLogger : ILogger {}

[Export("logger", typeof(ILogger))]
public class logger: ILogger {}
```

And the requesting type in the  Foo.UI.* decorate like this

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MyService([Import("clientLogger", typeof(ILogger))]ILogger logger)
```

I know that it's not the best solution but maybe it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas's solution using named exports is probably the best you can do with the .NET 4 version of MEF.  With next version of MEF, you can probably use a convention via the [RegistrationBuilder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2011/03/08/mef-s-convention-model.aspx) to change any ILogger imports in the UI namespace to be named imports.  IE, effectively doing what Thomas suggested but doing it by convention instead of having to apply it to each of your classes.

A preview of the next version of MEF is available on [codeplex](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Daniel, good to know :) Looking forward to the next release :)